# "The operation has timed out" when trying to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();
        ms.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox1 .Text ));
        ms.Subject = TextBox2.Text;
        ms.Body = TextBox3.Text;
        ms.IsBodyHtml = true;
        sm.Send(ms);
    }
    catch (Exception el)
    {
        Response.Write(el.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution with full source code?

Answer (score 1):

The SmtpClient gets its configuration from the web.config, i.e. SMTP server address and authentication fields if needed. Put a breakpoint on the Send line, examine the settings of your sm object,  make sure that the SMTP parameters are correct, and that you can hit the server from wherever you are testing this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the connection settings (example for GMail):

```
SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
sm.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password");
sm.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you're not able to connect to the SMTP server, hence the timeout message. There are several possibilities why this problem has occurred:

- Wrong SMTP address
- SMTP rejected
- SMTP server is offline
- Port setting
- SSL configuration

Answer (score 0):

please Enter this in `web.config` file

```
<system.net>
            <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="yourEmailId@gmail.com">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="yourEmailId@gmail.com" password="***** " defaultCredentials="false"/>
              </smtp>
            </mailSettings>
        </system.net>
```